# Three triangles have three lines vs. three triangles have nine lines

Tags: expressions

> Each triangle has three lines.

Which one is correct, (or are both correct)? 'Three triangles have three lines' or 'three triangles have nine lines.'

Please don't insert adverb 'each'.

(I try to know the expression just about English, not about mathematics.)

Comment: Using 'Each' is the correct / most sensible way to disambiguate - why preclude it?

Comment: @Mike Brockington No, I don't try to disambiguate. Just about grammatical correctness!

Comment: If you leave it ambiguous, then no-one can honestly claim that it is 'correct'.  And asking for the 'correct grammar' misses the point that in English, that means 'normal usage' which would involve the word 'each' in the majority of cases.

Comment: @Mike Brockington I'm interested in fundamental linguistics/I want to treat English as computer language.

Comment: There is the problem.  It isn't a computer language.

Comment: @James K but I believe English can be a perfect language like computer language.

Comment: That doesn't make sense!

Comment: In terms of grammatical correctness:

>"Three triangles have three lines" 
>
>"Three triangles have nine lines"

Are both correct and grammatically well-formed sentences in English. 

but so is 

> "Seven triangles have two hundred and ninety-three lines."

Comment: In any case, we say that a triangle has three **sides**, not lines. Since a triangle is by definition a 3-sided shape, you could say 'Three triangles have nine sides', with 'between them' being understood.

Answer (score 2):

Three triangles have nine sides in total.

As KateBunting said in a comment we usually talk of the sides of a triangle not lines.